# WPF binding behavior

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have page like this ...

```
<Page x:Class="WPFTestRig.Page1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Page1">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="myBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEntryValue}" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedEntryValue}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

with code behind as

```
 public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    private List<Entry> _myCollection;
    private string _selectedEntryValue;
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myCollection = new List<Entry>();
        _myCollection.Add(new Entry { Name = "Test1", Id = 1 });
        _myCollection.Add(new Entry { Name = "Test2", Id = 2 });
        _myCollection.Add(new Entry { Name = "Test3", Id = 3 });

        _selectedEntryValue = "Test3";

        myBox.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<Entry> MyCollection
    {
        get {
            return _myCollection;
        }
    }
    public string SelectedEntryValue
    {
        get {
            return _selectedEntryValue;
        }
        set { 
            _selectedEntryValue = value ;
        }
    }

}

public class Entry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

when i put a break point on set property of SelectedEntryValue property, i see it gets called twice, once with the string of the type name like (MyTestApp.Entry) and then the actual selected value

can someone point out what i should be doing for it to work right ?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing that behavior because you bind it to both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`, thus it executes twice. The first time it is bound it appears the displayed property is not being used yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you accidentally bound both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`.

You wrote (reformatted for readability):

```
<ComboBox Name="myBox" ... SelectedValuePath="Name" ...
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEntryValue}"
  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedEntryValue}" />
```

Remove the `SelectedItem` binding and you will get the behavior you expect.